# Change date format in wordpress to relative date

Tags: php, wordpress

Need a bit of help here as I am not really familiar with PHP.  I have two post type and one is displaying date in "x time ago" format and one is display the traditional wordpress date format.

I found this line in my wordpress theme that display the traditional format on my post.

```
$postheader .= '<abbr class="published" title="' . get_the_time('c') . '">' . get_the_time( get_option('date_format') ) . '</abbr></span>';
```

Now this theme already has a pre-written function to display time in x minutes, days, weeks, years ago as defined to be '%s' and it's being used in the code below

```
<abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('c') ?>"><?php printf( __('%s', 'arras'), arras_posted_on( false ) ) ?></abbr> | <a href="<?php comments_link() ?>"><?php comments_number() ?></a>
```

My question is .. how to modify the first code to display the format in "x time ago" like the one being used in the second code?  I tried to paste the exact same line and it made my page goes blank when reload.

Comment: Check your server logs. Any parse errors are shown there and will help you to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
$postheader .= '<abbr class="published" title="' . arras_posted_on( false ) . '">' . arras_posted_on( false ) . '</abbr></span>';
```